# save video from story board to media library WP7

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

is there a way to capture or to save the story board animation to media library in windows mobile? Currently i am working with an animation which changes the image for every second. How can i save this into a video format??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism to save any video content to Media Library.

Currently, using API, you can save pictures. Nothing else

Please see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary_members.aspx